# Выделение слайдера при использовании Swiper JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

При попытке свайпа в месте между слайдами начинает выделяться слайдер (при чем только на тех слайдах, которые дальше первых слайдов). Можно ли это исправить?

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: 2,
  mousewheel: true,
  spaceBetween: 25,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

Вот пример: https://codepen.io/w1zl/pen/JjexwjW

Answer (score 0):

Задай классу `swiper-slide` свойство `user-select: none`

```
.swiper-slide {
  user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, ты используешь slider Swiper, и у тебя есть .slider-container с несколькими .swiper-slide. Предложу такое :

```
.swiper-container > .swiper-slide:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Так же вместо none можно использовать transparent, (прозрачный)